# Multiple APK, support for multiple resolution, <supports-screens> how to write

Tags: android, resolution

I created a game application, it supports

- 800_480
- 1024_600
- 1280_720
- 1920_1080

  this four
  resolution, I will create four `apk`, uploaded to the Google play, each `apk` can only support a resolution, each apk's tag(supports-screens) how to write? Thank you everyone!

Comment: Why are you creating 4 versions of the same thing? You can just create the one app to to support all screen sizes

Comment: I don't want a APK contains four sets of resources, will greatly increase the capacity of APK

Comment: Play allowed to same version upload in 4 Apk ? :)

Comment: yes, google play allowed.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your application the following tags having boolean values can change. For example, if you want to build app for Large Screens, AndroidManifest.xml would be like this:

```
<manifest>
     <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false" android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="false" />
     <application>
          <activity/>
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't understand how these attributes is the corresponding resolution, such as largeScreens, which is corresponding to inch, but such as 1280x720  resolution, 4 inch 's mobile and 7 inch's tablet   all support